# Getting error for AWS accesskeyid from my AWS Educate Account

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, multer-s3

I have an AWS educate account & want to use s3 bucket for storing images using multer. For the same, I got aws_access_key_id & aws_secret_access_key from vocareum workbench. But when I am using these id & secret key, I am getting an error of
`"The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records." & "InvalidAccessKeyId"`

So, can anyone help me out here, why is it showing me an error in spite of using the access_key_id & secret_access_key?

Comment: I think that AWS Educate credentials are only valid for a short duration. You can direct questions to: https://aws.amazon.com/education/awseducate/contact-us/

Comment: Yeah, I have contacted them. They said it won't be accessible to any express app. Anyway thanks. @JohnRotenstein